# remove certain columns from a matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have a matrix A with n columns and matrix B with m < n columns. All columns of B are contained in the columns of A. I want to select those columns in A (the ones which are common in A and B) and remove them such that I am left with n-m columns in A. Is there a way to do this directly in Mathematica?

Comment: Just a warning, you accepted an answer that produces an incorrect result (if your question is correctly phrased).  Even after it was changed (to use transpose), it will reorder the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each element in B was contained in A, then`Complement[A,B]` would do fine. For example, suppose `A={{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}` and `B={{1, 2}, {3, 4}}`, then it would be `Complement[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]`, which would give out `{{5,6}}`
-----a correction---------
I mistaken the meaning of the word "column", the correct code should be
`Transpose@Complement[Transpose@A,Transpose@B]`

Comment: OP wanted columns, not rows.

Comment: `Complement` reorders ...

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer `DeleteCases` over replacement rules. Even faster is using `Tally` in conjunction with `Pick`.

```
n = 1000;
m = 100;
idx = RandomChoice[Range[n], m];
A = RandomInteger[{0, 1000}, {n, n}];
B = A[[All, idx]];

a = Transpose[ Transpose[A] /. {x_List /; MemberQ[Transpose[B], x] -> Nothing}]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
b = Transpose[DeleteCases[Transpose[A], Alternatives @@ Transpose[B]]]; //
   RepeatedTiming // First
c = Transpose[
     Pick[##, 1] & @@ 
      Transpose[Tally[Join[Transpose[A], Transpose[B]]]]]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
a == b == c
```

> 0.364
>
> 0.018
>
> 0.010
>
> True

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Fold` to delete repeatedly from the transposed list, and transpose back to the original:

```
Transpose@Fold[DeleteCases, Transpose[A], Transpose[B]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(* fake data *)
mA = RandomInteger[{0, 1000}, {10, 5}]
mB = mA[[All, {1, 3, 5}]]
(* the answer to your question: *)
Transpose[Transpose[mA] /. {x_List /; MemberQ[Transpose[mB], x] -> Nothing}]
```